# Detecting which words are the same between two pieces of text

Tags: python, algorithm

I need some python advice to implement an algorithm.

What I need is to detect which words from text 1 are in text 2:

> Text 1: "Mary had a dog. The dog's name was Ethan. He used to run down
>   the meadow, enjoying the flower's scent."
>
> Text 2: "Mary had a cat. The cat's name was Coco. He used to run down
>   the street, enjoying the blue sky."

I'm thinking I could use some pandas datatype to check repetitions, but I'm not sure.

Any ideas on how to implement this would be very helpful. Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since you do not show any work of your own, I'll just give an overall algorithm.

First, split each text into its words. This can be done in several ways. You could remove any punctuation then split on spaces. You need to decide if an apostrophe as in `dog's` is part of the word--you probably want to leave apostrophes in. But remove periods, commas, and so forth.

Second, place the words for each text into a set.

Third, use the built-in set operations to find which words are in both sets.

This will answer your actual question. If you want a different question that involves the counts or positions of the words, you should make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary to first store words from first text and than just simply look up while iterating the second text. But this will take space.

So best way is to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

First extract words from both strings into lists. I assume you would want to ignore any trailing periods or commas. Add one of the lists to a set (for expected constant time lookup). For each word in another list, check if it's also present in the set; That gets you words common in both of the texts. I assumed that duplicate elements are counted only once. Following is the code for doing this:

```
def get_words(text):
    words = text.split()
    for i in range(len(words)):
        words[i] = words[i].strip('.,')
    return words

def common_words(text1, text2):
    words1 = get_words(text1)
    words2 = set(get_words(text2))
    common = set()
    for word in words1:
        if word in words2:
            common.add(word)
    return common
```

For your example, it would return:

```
{'enjoying', 'had', 'to', 'Mary', 'used', 'the', 'The', 'was', 'down', 'name', 'He', 'run', 'a'}
```

Note that words "the" and "The" are counted as distinct. If you don't want that, you can convert all words to lower case; `words[i] = lower(words[i].strip('.,'))`